# Using DAX, how do I create a measure to sum a column from the most recent records so I can display the total by date?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I would like to take this table:

| ID | CID | Term | Date | FTE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 21SP | 12/21/2020 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 | 21SP | 12/21/2020 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 21SP | 12/23/2020 | 0 |
| 1 | 2 | 21SP | 12/23/2020 | 0 |
| 1 | 3 | 21SP | 12/23/2020 | 1 |
| 1 | 4 | 21SP | 01/01/2021 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 21SP | 12/25/2020 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 21SP | 12/25/2020 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 21SP | 01/02/2021 | 0 |
| 3 | 1 | 21SP | 01/02/2021 | 1 |

and turn it into a visualized table (and corresponding graph) like this:

| Term | Date | FTE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 21SP | 12/21/2020 | 2 |
| 21SP | 12/22/2020 | 2 |
| 21SP | 12/23/2020 | 1 |
| 21SP | 12/24/2020 | 1 |
| 21SP | 12/25/2020 | 3 |
| 21SP | 12/26/2020 | 3 |
| 21SP | 12/27/2020 | 3 |
| 21SP | 12/28/2020 | 3 |
| 21SP | 12/29/2020 | 3 |
| 21SP | 12/30/2020 | 3 |
| 21SP | 12/31/2020 | 3 |
| 21SP | 01/01/2021 | 4 |
| 21SP | 01/02/2021 | 4 |

and so on...

Each row in the visualization is a sum of the FTE column for the most recent record up to that date, per ID, CID, and Term. So, for example, on 01/01/2021, the visualization is adding up the following records:

| ID | CID | Term | Date | FTE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 21SP | 12/23/2020 | 0 |
| 1 | 2 | 21SP | 12/23/2020 | 0 |
| 1 | 3 | 21SP | 12/23/2020 | 1 |
| 1 | 4 | 21SP | 01/01/2021 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 21SP | 12/25/2020 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 21SP | 12/25/2020 | 1 |

I also have a date table that has all the dates between the start and end dates of this table.

I am bumfuzzled. I am pretty sure I need to create a measure that starts like:

```
FTE by Date = 
VAR CurrentDate = SELECTEDVALUE( Dates[Date] )
...
RETURN
   ???
```

That is all I can muster at this point. My knowledge of DAX is nowhere near this level, I am afraid. Any help would be GREATLY appreciated. I am sure something like this has been asked before so point me in the right direction and I will go read some more.

Thanks.

Edit (2021-03-09): Added logic description per comment by @mkRabbani.

Comment: You do not explain the logic for the transformed data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's first define a measure that will return the most recent date for a particular `ID`, `CID`, `Term` combination.

```
MostRecent =
VAR CurrentDate = SELECTEDVALUE ( 'Date'[Date] )
RETURN
    CALCULATE (
        MAX ( Table1[Date] ),
        ALLEXCEPT ( Table1, Table1[ID], Table1[CID], Table1[Term] ),
        Table1[Date] <= CurrentDate
    )
```

Using this measure, writing a `FTE by Date` measure becomes much easier:

```
FTE by Date = 
SUMX (
    FILTER ( ALLEXCEPT ( Table1, Table1[Term] ), Table1[Date] = [MostRecent] ),
    Table1[FTE]
)
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not a cumulative total. The previous values of the group are ignored.

Comment: I've rewritten my answer. Have another look.

Comment: This works wonderfully! Thank you. I was getting so close but just could not wrap my head around this.

Comment: This one really made me think. The result is deceptively simple-looking.